# get Django "self.request.user" with Token authentication

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have a Django Rest/ Vue.js application. I was using basic Django authentication but since it is a Single Page Application, I switched to Token Authentication so I can manage login/logout/register through an endpoint and get a more consistent application.

Overall is working fine but my main problem is that I made some permissions and override some viewsets. I have to disable them in order to have my app to work with token authentication:

My permissions:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

    class IsOwnReviewOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    
        def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
            if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
                return True
    
            return obj.restaurant_review.review_author == request.user
    
    class IsAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    
        def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
            if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
                return True
    
            return obj.review_author == request.user
```

And my viewset:

```
class RestaurantReviewViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.RestaurantReview.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return serializers.RestaurantReviewGETSerializer 
        else:
            return serializers.RestaurantReviewSerializer 

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(review_author=self.request.user)
```

So my guess is that Django can't find `request.user`, is it related to my new authentication? Can Token Authentication provide it?

Comment: post your settings.py (REST FRAMEWORK SETTINGS).